# Hide the element if the length and ng-pattern not satisfied angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I only need to show the span if the user input value is greater than 1 and the input field doesn't contains the values defined in the regular expression.

Code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example - example-ng-form-production</title>


  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular-animate.js"></script>


  <script type="text/javascript">
    angular.element(document.getElementsByTagName('head')).append(angular.element('<base href="' + window.location.pathname + '" />'));
  </script>
</head>

<body ng-app="formExample">
  <script>
    angular.module('formExample', [])
      .controller('FormController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
        $scope.userType = '';
        $scope.regex = "#%<;'=";
      }]);
  </script>
  <form name="myForm" ng-controller="FormController" class="my-form">
    userType:
    <input name="input" ng-model="userType" ng-pattern="regex && userType">
    <span ng-show="userType && myForm.input.$valid">show me!</span>
    <br>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

[Plunker Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/xs2beXGoSnHUiIRG4DKw?p=preview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need a entry without your regex pattern, you need a exclusion mask:

```
$scope.regex = "[^#%<;'=]*";
```

And use a not conditional mask on pattern:

```
<input name="input" ng-model="userType" ng-pattern="regex">
```

plunker [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/IjPknAJWHqW5bekvyLGC?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

ng-pattern only validates regular expression. So inside ng-pattern there should be just pattern. At the time of showing message check the userType and the other form property inside ng-show or ng-hide. That's all.

```
<form name="myForm" ng-controller="FormController" class="my-form">
userType:
<input name="input" ng-model="userType" ng-pattern="regex">
<span ng-show="userType && !myForm.input.$error.pattern">show me!</span>
<br>
```

Comment: give an example of pattern

Comment: Added in plunker as well as it is there in the code attached

Comment: Code-only answers are terrible.  What did you change? Why does it work? What did the OP need to do differently?

Comment: Yeah, got the plunker. I just wanted to know about the regular expression. suppose there is regular expression for email validation, phone no validation etc. What type of string your regular expression validates. By the way i have edited my answer. there was a logical error.